# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found after deploying project to Tomcat

Tags: mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I had a webproject in Eclipse, which uses a connection to my mysql database.

I exported the project as .WAR-File and deployed it on a different machine to the tomcat server. On that machine there is also the mysql-database.

I do this:

```
envContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup( "java:comp/env/jdbc/Database" );
con = ds.getConnection();
```

My Context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/Database" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="user"
        password="pw"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename"/>
```

But I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at bachelor.Cronjob.run(Cronjob.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThr$
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPool$
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
        ... 29 more
```

In the "WEB-INF/lib"-Folder I got the 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar'.

Does anyone know why it works in eclipse but not in tomcat on the other machine? Thanks alot!

Comment: What is the exact code which caused the exception?  Could you include more of the stack trace?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Please see my edits.

Comment: Open your `.war` file with any `zip` extraction tool and check whether it consists `mysql-connector.jar` file. If it is not there that might be a problem. Your error log states that class not found for mysql-connection.

Comment: @Shashanth He mentioned that his exploded `WEB-INF/lib` folder has the JAR.  Which makes this question interesting.

Comment: @Shashanth: After deploying the war-file there is the folder under tomcat/webapps. And I checked, the connector.jar is in the lib folder.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, yeah absolutely interesting question.

Comment: I am almost sure that if you use a JNDI datasource defined in Context.xml, the DB driver has to be in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, i.e. it is not enough to have it in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek: Where is this lib-folder? I can't find it under /var/lib/tomcat7/

Comment: @progNewbie It's in the `$CATALINA_HOME` directory, and where the `$CATALINA_HOME` is, depends on your installation. Probably the easiest way to find out is to run `ps axwww | grep -i catalina` command and then look for the `-Dcatalina.home=...` option.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek: Nice now it works!! Please write an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am almost sure that if you use a JNDI datasource defined in `Context.xml`, the DB driver has to be in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, i.e. it is not enough to have it in `WEB-INF/lib`.

(Some Tomcat installations have different `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE`, so if you cannot find the proper `lib` folder, then probably the easiest way to find where it is is to run `ps axwww | grep -i catalina` command and then to look for the `-Dcatalina.home=...` option.)